# Curl not working with CSRF token in REST POST

Tags: rest, curl, post

REST: `POST` fails with `CSRF` enabled, though it works in `POSTMAN`.
I have added several headers like `-H Set Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxx` along with `-H X-CSRF-TOKEN: bbbb`, `-b cookies.txt` after generating it. I would like to know what exactly has to be added to make the request work ?

Comment: if i recall postman has a curl generator, that will generate the curl for you

Comment: yes, it generates curl. But using the same isn't working outside postman.